# ngForm with ngControl is not working

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-forms

I have started working on Angular2 and I have a problem dealing with ngForm and ngControl . I am trying to console.log the value that I am fetching from the form but when checking the console , the object is shown to be empty.
Below is the TypeScript and HTML Code

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  onSubmit(f) {
    console.log(f.value);
  }
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

```html
<h1> Registeration Form </h1>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <div>
    <label for='mail'>Mail </label>
    <input ngControl="email" type='text' id='mail' required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='password'>password </label>
    <input ngControl="password" type='text' id='password' required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='confirm-password'>Confirm Password </label>
    <input ngControl="confirm-password" type='text' id='confirm-password' required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <div>
    <label for='mail'>Mail </label>
    <input ngControl="email" name="email" type='text' id='mail' ngModel required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='password'>password </label>
    <input ngControl="password" name="password" type='text' id='password'  ngModel required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='confirm-password'>Confirm Password </label>
    <input ngControl="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" ngModel type='text' id='confirm-password' required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form> 
    try by giving name, ngModel to inputs
```